# subprocess to print stderr and stdout in real-time

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, real-time, stderr

Say I have this program `printer.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write("STDOUT 1\n")
time.sleep(1)
sys.stderr.write("STDERR 2\n")
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write("STDOUT 3\n")
time.sleep(1)
sys.stderr.write("STDERR 4\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

It prints to stdout and stderr to produce:

```
./printer.py 
STDOUT 1
STDERR 2
STDOUT 3
STDERR 4
```

I would like to execute `printer.py` inside another python script, `runner.py`, and print in real time both stderr and stdout. The following version of `runner.py` does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline().decode()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip())
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc

rc = run_command('./printer.py')
```

because it prints the stderr lines first in real-time and the stdout lines later all at once:

```
./runner.py 
STDERR 2
STDERR 4
STDOUT 1
STDOUT 3
```

How can fix it to have the correct order 1, 2, 3, and 4 in real-time? The closer I could get is by using:

```
rc = run_command('./printer.py 1>&2')
```

which is kind of ok, but I wonder whether I could make it do the proper thing and print to stdout and stderr in the same way as `printer.py`.

---

`sys.stdout.flush()` as suggested in comments makes no difference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline().decode()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            sys.stdout.write(output.strip() + '\n')
            sys.stdout.flush()
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc

rc = run_command('./printer.py')
```

```
./runner.py 
STDERR 2
STDERR 4
STDOUT 1
STDOUT 3
```

The same for `print(..., flush=True)`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `sys.stdout.flush()` to flush the output buffer.

Comment: @Barmar where do I put `sys.stdout.flush()`? I tried various places and it makes no difference.

Comment: After each `sys.stdout.write()`

Comment: You can also use `print(something, flush=True)`. Little is gained by using `sys.stdout.write()` instead of `print()`.

Comment: @Barmar see edited question... `flush` doesn't seem to work for me!

Comment: You have to do it in `printer.py`, not `runner.py`. That's where the output is buffered because it's writing to a pipe.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I see. The problem is I have no control over `printer.py` (this is just an MWE). Is `rc = run_command('./printer.py 1>&2')` my best option then?

Comment: Use the `unbuffer` command to run the child process.

Comment: Try `run_command('python -u ./printer.py')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell and Barmar: see my answer below. Feel free to post yours and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm collating comments and add a bit of mine. Credit goes to @Barmar and @MarkSetchell.

In the end, I think I'm going for the following solution:

```
rc = run_command('PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ./printer.py')
```

it should do the same as @MarkSetchell's `python -u ./printer.py`. However, for that I would to explicitly set the path to `printer.py` and I would rather avoid that. But I'm not sure yet about the pro and cons of each.

`unbuffer` solution: On my Ubuntu 18 is not installed so I'd rather avoid an additional dependency. As I understand it I would use it as `rc = run_command('unbuffer ./printer.py')`?

Editing `printer.py` is not an option for me otherwise adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print` or `sys.stdout.write` should also work.